# Fizbuzz in OCaml gets gets error "is not compatible with type unit"

Tags: ocaml

I have the following fizbuzz program written in OCaml (using a bit of recursion):

```
let rec fizbuzz_r = 
  let rec fizbuzz_rr i = 
    if i == 0 then 
      ()
    else if i mod 3 == 0 && i mod 5 != 0 then
      Printf.printf "Fizz: %d \n" i  
      fizbuzz_rr (i - 1)
    else if i mod 3 != 0 && i mod 5 == 0 then
      Printf.printf "Buzz: %d \n" i 
      fizbuzz_rr (i - 1) 
    else if i mod 5 == 0 && i mod 3 == 0 then
      Printf.printf "Fizbuzz: %d \n" i 
      fizbuzz_rr (i - 1) 
    else 
      Printf.printf "Current Number: %d \n" i 
      fizbuzz_rr (i - 1) 
    ()
  in  
    fizbuzz_rr 100

let () = fizbuzz_r
```

The problem is when I compile it, I get the following error message:

```
Error: This expression has type
         ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd, out_channel, unit, unit, unit,
          'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       Type 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd is not compatible with type unit
```

However, it seems to me that the nested function `fizbuzz_rr` is correctly returning a `unit` type. What am I missing here?

Comment: I strongly suggest you avoid using `==` and `!=`. They may behave like you think they do on integers, but they may break everything on other types. Try using `=` and `<>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression:

```
  Printf.printf "Fizz: %d \n" i  
  fizbuzz_rr (i - 1)
```

Has the form of a call to `Printf.printf` with 4 arguments. You need a semicolon to separate the two expressions that you want to have.

However, after `then` you can only have one expression. So you need to parenthesize the two expressions. It will look like this:

```
  . . .
else if i mod 3 == 0 && i mod 5 != 0 then (
  Printf.printf "Fizz: %d \n" i;
  fizbuzz_rr (i - 1)
) else if i mod 3 != 0 && i mod 5 == 0 then (
  . . .
```

You also have an extra `()` at the end that is not doing anything. You should remove it like this:

```
else (
  Printf.printf "Current Number: %d \n" i ;
  fizbuzz_rr (i - 1)
)
```

Comment: Thanks! If I understood correctly, parenthesization returns the unit type?

Comment: No, it returns the value (hence type) of what's inside the parentheses.The value and type of `a; b` is the value and type of `b`. So you do have unit type in your case.